# Build frontend проекта с jQuery Bootstrap на Grunt Gulp

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, gulp, npm, grunt

Возможно ли сделать так, что все собственно написанные исходники и исходники из папки `npm_modules` строились (компилировались) в папку с публичной версией проекта, автоматом без ручного копирования из папки с Bootstrap  и jQuery исходниками?
Это писать правильно в ручную или есть какая-то команда?

Answer (score 0):

https://andwecode.com/better-frontend-with-gulp-and-bower/
из исходников bootstrap и jquery можно все построить в свою папку с публичной версией, но это не обязательно, короче легче ручками...

Comment: Опишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы пользователи могли легко понять ваш ответ. Чтобы редактировать ответ, нажмите [edit].